# How to load a list of large images without scaling?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I'm trying to view a list of large images (about 21000x600 in total of all images) in a ListView with ZoomControls, I successfully viewed the images, but it runs out of memory when on maximum zoom.

Here's my code for `getView` :

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    Options opts = new Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = zoomModifier;
    opts.inScaled = true;
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    Bitmap p = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + (arg0+1) + ".jpg", opts);
    iv.setImageBitmap(p);
    return new ImageView(context);
}
```

The pictures must be loaded unscaled for maximum zoom.

I was wondering if there's andother memory safe way to do this?

Comment: Considering that's about 35MB per image, you are unlikely to get more than one to load successfully, let alone several in a list. On many devices, you will not even get one to load. I would suggest that you come up with a different strategy for whatever it is you are trying to build.

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant all of them together would be in this resolution , combined

Comment: I can get 3-4 pictures to load, If I can unload the ones loaded in the beginning it would run as I expect